# What is the interval of convergence of $\sin( x)\ln(1+x)$?

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

I know how to calculate the interval of convergence of single functions as MacLaurin series. But how to do when we have a product of two functions.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Well, if you multiply two real numbers together, you get a real number. So the product converges if and only if both converge, right?

Comment: @JoshuaWang Mh, there is a flaw in this reasoning: the development of $(x+1)\cdot\dfrac1{x+1}$ converges for all reals.

Comment: If both f(x) and g(x) have convergent Taylor series on an interval, then so does the product f(x)g(x).